# Zener Diode identification - Ultimate Speed Battery Charger

Tags: power-supply, diodes, charger, zener

Friend of mine came with this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ultimate-Speed-Battery-Charger-Motorcycles/dp/B00JKOA7H8

The charger powered up. Display showed battery voltage, but it didn't switched to charge. After some digging, I found one trace to be burned down. I fixed that path. But the charger is now giving 16 Volts instead of like 14V and the display shows Error. I found out that one of the SMD Zener diodes is shorted. This one probably serves as part of the sensing circuit, and thats why the display shows error.

So right now I am trying to replace it. As I couldn't find any datasheet, my options are limited. I could recreate the schema, if its needed.

[image: Purple line from the left was burned. Yellow SMD Zener diode is dead - Only one letter "D" as a description]
Purple line from the left was burned. Yellow SMD Zener diode is dead - Only one letter "D" as a description. Next to it (red) is Opto-isolator. And two (blue) ceramic discs capacitors.

I assume that this pattern (schema) is similar in almost all battery chargers. So what voltage range are we talking about here so I can narrow the search for the replacement?

And how would you advice I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: buy a new charger

Comment: It's not about the money. He already bought one. It's about education.

Comment: ok then ... draw a schematic diagram

Comment: also, add the comment about education to your question

Comment: Most likely failed by design by disconnecting/connecting charger with power on with surge or flyback failure..., as I do not see any protection circuits.  Easy way to debug is compare with working unit.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yep. I was thinking the same. And luckily, we know a guy that has the same device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found out that one of the SMD Zener diodes is shorted
> ...
> Yellow SMD Zener diode is dead

Actually, no, it isn't a dead Zener diode. See below for details.

> Only one letter "D" as a description.

Here is the relevant part of the photo you supplied:

[image: cropped part of the photo supplied in the question]

That part you have indicated with the yellow arrow (silkscreen designator "DZ2") is a "zero-ohm jumper". FYI that's a "0" marked on the component.

So either:

- The manufacturer wrongly installed a zero-ohm jumper, in place of the correct component which should be in position DZ2.

Or:

- The designer decided that the component (likely Zener diode, yes) intended to be originally fitted as DZ2 is no longer required (due to cost saving, or changes to other components, or any other valid reason) and so it has been *deliberately* replaced with a zero-ohm jumper.

  I suspect that this situation applies, since Zener diode DZ3 also seems to be in series with the photodiode in the opto-coupler. It would be reasonable to only need one of them.

You will need to reverse-engineer the circuit some more, to figure out which of those two cases applies, and to find the *real* fault.

But the summary is: The component fitted in the position for DZ2 *is supposed to be shorted*. So that is why you measure it as shorted.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpfull. I didn't realize that there was just a thing like zero ohm jumpers. But it explains everything. Alright. I will keep an eye for additional errors I find. I accept this answer.

Comment: And I am sorry about misleading description. It looked like zener diode in SMC Case.